# Finding the maximum of a function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I can’t find the maximum of the function, although the graph shows that it exists. Maximaze and FindMaximum give different results. However, these results do not coincide with the graph.

```
\[Alpha] = 1.322; a = 0.061; b = 0.71;
\[CapitalPsi][x_] = \[Alpha] x ((a^b + 1)/(a^b + x^b))^(1/b);
y[x_] = Sqrt[1 - x^2];
M[x_] = \[CapitalPsi][x] y[x];
M1[x_] = D[M[x], x];
Maximize[{M[x], Re[x] >= 0}, x]
FindMaximum[M[x], x]
```

I tried to solve it through Solve, but nothing worked either, everything hangs:

```
Solve[M1[x] == 0, x]
```

It is clear that the graph of the derivative passes through 0:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Did you try `FindMaximum[M[x], {x, 1/2}]` according to the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like user64494 commented:

```
max = FindMaximum[M[x], {x, 1/2}]
```

{1.04545, {x -> 0.412278}}

```
pxy = {Values @ max[[2, 1]], max[[1]]}
```

{0.412278, 1.04545}

```
Plot[{M[x], M1[x], 1}, {x, 0, 1},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[pxy]},
 GridLines -> List /@ pxy,
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[0.004], Dashed],
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 PlotRange -> {-1.5, 1.5}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

To answer the comment

You must restrict the domain to `Reals`

```
Solve[M1[x] == 0., x, Reals] // Quiet
```

{{x -> 0.412278}}

But even then `Solve` complains and issues the message:

*Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.*

You can surpress this message with `Quiet` or, preferably, use one of the numeric solvers:

```
NSolve[M1[x] == 0., x, Reals]
```

{{x -> 0.412278}}

```
NMaximize[M[x], x]
```

{1.04545, {x -> 0.412278}}

```
FindMaximum[M[x], {x, 0}]
```

{1.04545, {x -> 0.412278}}

Please note that you can also choose the "easier" `0` as starting point for `FindMaximum`.

Comment: thanks a lot. Am I understanding correctly that solving the Find Maximum function sometimes requires an approximate solution? Can you tell me why it doesn't work for me
`Solve[M1[x] == 0, x]
`?

Comment: Please see updated answer

Comment: thanks again. I am very grateful to you.

Comment: My pleasure - you can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark at the upper left of my answer. And you can upvote it by clicking the upper triangle.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

α = 1.322 // Rationalize;
a = 0.061 // Rationalize;
b = 0.71 // Rationalize;
Ψ[x_] = α x ((a^b + 1)/(a^b + x^b))^(1/b);
y[x_] = Sqrt[1 - x^2];
M[x_] = Ψ[x] y[x];

M1[x_] = D[M[x], x] // Simplify;
```

With exact input, the exact result is

```
{max, arg} = Maximize[{M[x], x >= 0}, x] // Simplify
```

[image]

Which is approximately,

```
{max, arg} // N

(* {1.04545, {x -> 0.412278}} *)
```

Using [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html),

```
arg2 = NSolve[{M1[x] == 0, 0 <= x}, x, Reals][[1]]

(* {x -> 0.412278} *)

M[x] /. arg2

(* 1.04545 *)
```